# ng-include with template does not render data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two java script - one for controller and one for data service call.

On index page, I try to load tab with data from database returned results. It throws undefined for scope data which I can see already set but it seems html renders before that

Index page

```
<li ng-repeat="(Id, Name) in data.list" ng-class="{active: isSel(Id)}">
<a ng-click="isChange(Id, Name);" ng-href="#{{Name}}" role="pill" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tab">
{{Name}}
</a>
</li>


<div class="tab-content">
<div ng-repeat="(Id, Name) in data.list" class="tab-pane template fade in" id="{{Name}}" ng-class="{active: isSel(Id)}">
<div class="row" ng-include="'templates/my_widget.html'" >  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

my_widget.html

```
<div class="col-md-4 component list-widget" ng-repeat="(Id, Name) in data.LatestBList">......blah blah....</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.isSelected = function(entry) {
        return $scope.tab === entry;
  };

  $scope.isChange = function(Id, Name) {
        $scope.tab = Id;
        $scope.Name = Name;
        $scope.data.LatestBList= [];
        $scope.data.LatestBList= ds.getList($scope.Name); // database retuned list
  };
```

I get the error like

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=(Id%2C%20Name)%20in%20data.LatestBList&p1=undefined%3Aundefined&p2=undefined
    at Error (<anonymous>
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: ur code looks fine. in ng-repeat u are having an array that  has duplicate value.ng-repeat wont allow duplicates.console.log both data.list.remove duplicates

Comment: Use `ng-repeat="(Id, Name) in data.List track by $index"`

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks, sorry my bad question was not correct. I have updated.

Comment: @P P problem remains the same.remove duplicates or if u want to keep duplicates use georgeawg's answer

Comment: @sundar well, I tried georgeawg solution as well. But neighter works. Same error..in error it is mentioned that both value of list is undefined.

Comment: @P P chk why  thats undefined

Comment: Both lists - list and LatestBList are different. It looks like isChange() function resets the LatestBList & assigns latest result from database but nginclude of my_widget renders before that. I can see the latest data in LatestBList in 2-3 seconds.

Comment: chk the undefined values

Comment: yes thats bcse of ajax call to ur server

Comment: Yes right..that is http.jsonp call. But it shouldnt have to be undefinded..not sure

Comment: ng-include gets created with its own scope hence it was returning un-defined. $parent solved the issue. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-include` gets created with its own scope hence it was returning undefined. `$parent` can be used to obtain the parent scope which solved the issue.